# VIdeo Recording like talking tom app

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, video-recording

How to capture Iphone Gameplay Screen as like talking tom app using cocos2D?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use AVAssetWriter for your work..
For more info..

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAssetWriter_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Hope this helps. :)

Comment: Thanks Nikhil Aneja..Is there any sample code using AVAssetWriter to record iphone screen?:(